# Adding custom text to UITextField buffer

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, buffer, homekit

**Background:** I have got a custom alert part of the HomeKit API. I'd like to allow the user to paste the code requested rather than inputting it manually.

[image]

Whenever there is text in the buffer it is possible to paste it by tapping on the textfield. How can I add custom text (from my App) to "this" buffer so the **"paste" option** appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate the iPhone clipboard using below code. Put this code to a suitable place in your code.

```
UIPasteboard *clipboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];  
clipboard.string = @"<Assign Some value>";
```